# RegExp first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working a JavaScript context detector.

It parses the UA for some common data like OS version and browser version.

It uses RegExp for pretty much everything.

Like the script to detect the Mac OS X version: `/(Intel|PPC) Mac OS X (.+)[\);]/`

It saves the data to an object that I'll call `$`.

`$.Mac` should be `10_6_7` but instead it is `10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko`

The full ua is `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.25 Safari/534.24`

It always uses the last found ; or ), when I want it to find the ; or ) immediately after the version number. How to do that?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? It already has this. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: WHYDOESEVERYONEUSEJQUERYFOREVERYTHING.

Comment: And it wouldn't work. It doesn't give the real version number for Chrome/Safari, and has no OS data.

Comment: I only mentioned it because of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:612367+[jquery].

Comment: Ahh. I like your answer more though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `.+` nongreedy.

```
/(Intel|PPC) Mac OS X (.+?)[\);]/
```

Before:

```
var str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.25 Safari/534.24',
    re = /(Intel|PPC) Mac OS X (.+)[\);]/;

str.match(re); // ["Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Intel", "10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko"]
```

After:

```
var re = /(Intel|PPC) Mac OS X (.+?)[\);]/;

str.match(re): // ["Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7)", "Intel", "10_6_7"]
```

Comment: I prefer to use `reg.exec(str)`.

Answer (score 1):

Or, make your `.+` more specific:

```
/(Intel|PPC) OS X ([0-9_]+)/
```

should do the trick, as long as you can count on your version numbers consisting only of digits and underscores.

Hope this helps!